# VNC error during live migration of KVM vm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, migration, vnc, live-migration

If I live migrate a KVM vm from host 1 to host2 then I get error for vnc. Is there any way to change the vnc dynamically before the migration starts. I donot want to stop and start my vm before or during mirgation.

**error: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-05-13T06:33:45.247345Z qemu-kvm: -vnc host1:785,password: Failed to start VNC server: Failed to bind socket: Cannot assign requested address**